# Como somar as parcelas não quitadas com SQL?

Tags: php, sql, count

Tenho 3 tabelas `faturas`, `parcelas` e `pagamentos`. Agora preciso montar um SQL para contar as parcelas que não estão quitadas. Já tentei um `SUM(CASE` mas não deu certo.

Estrutura da tabela `faturas`:

```
id_fa
tipo
data_emissao
valor_fatura
```

Estrutura da tabela `parcelas`:

```
id_pa
id_fatura
data_vcto
valor_parcela
```

Estrutura da tabela `pagamentos`:

```
id_pg
id_parcela
data_pgto
valor_bruto
valor_desconto
valor_juros
valor_multa
valor_pago
```

Minha tentativa de consulta:

```
SELECT 
id_pa, 
SUM(CASE WHEN lc_pagamentos.id_parcela=lc_parcelas.id_pa THEN lc_pagamentos.valor_bruto ELSE 0 END) AS vBruto 
FROM lc_faturas, lc_parcelas, lc_pagamentos 
WHERE lc_faturas.ID=lc_parcelas.ID
```

Desta forma  ele só conta a quantidade de parcelas, mas preciso que compare o campo `valor_parcela` da tabela `parcelas` com a soma do campo `valor_bruto` da tabela `pagamentos` e me retorne somente os registros que forem diferentes, ou seja, me retorne a parcela que não estiver quitada.

Comment: Poste a estrutura das tabelas envolvidas no processo.

Comment: vc deseja mostrar somente QUANTAS parcelas não foram quitadas, ou deseja LISTAR as parcelas não quitadas???

Comment: Preciso das duas situações, mas daí posso aproveitar o mesmo sql e fazer a contagem com mysql_num_rows. O que eu estou sofrendo mesmo é na montagem do sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saudações!

```
SELECT par.id_pa as Parcela, par.valor_parcela, valor_pago FROM parcelas AS par LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id_parcela, SUM(valor_bruto) as valor_pago FROM pagamentos GROUP BY id_parcela) as pgtos ON pgtos.id_parcela = par.id_pa
```

A consulta acima te mostrará o Id da Parcela, o valor da parcela e o valor pago até o momento (se houver pagamento para a parcela em questão). Se desejar apenas as parcelas que não foram quitadas (quitadas parcialmente ou que não receberam nenhum pagamento) adicione o seguinte trecho:

```
WHERE valor_pago < valor_parcela OR valor_pago IS NULL
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cara, perfeito, só adicionei mais um GROUP BY no final do WHERE pra agrupar pelo id_pa

Comment: Tem como melhorar a performance desta busca? Está demorando muito pra carregar, dando sobrecarga no servidor